# how to proxy IP address in Kubernetes container when requesting to foreign server

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, proxy, axios

I am trying to make a GET request to a foreign server. But the foreign server requires our IP address for security purposes.

Now the problem is I am running my app inside Kubernetes' pod with three nodes.
When I send the request, it takes the IP address of one of the kubernetes nodes.
I could add static IP addresses to all my nodes. But from what I have learned, best practice is to only release the Gateway(ingress) IP address to the outside world. Everything else should be hidden.

So I tried to proxy my axios request like this:

```
var res = await axios.get('https://someapi.com', {
    proxy: {
        host: 'ingressIP', //static ip
        port: 80
    }
});
```

But the request still returns an error saying that the IP is not allowed. It returned the IP address of the kubernetes node, where my POD was in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure, that you will be able to pass your traffic through ingress somehow.

We also had the same problem. We needed to send requests to a third-party server from a specific IP-address.

But we solved this a bit different, we just created a new small server with static IP, installed [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) proxy server there and configured our applications to use Squid server as an HTTP forward proxy.

Comment: A more proper term for "pass traffic over Squid server" is to "use Squid server as a HTTP forward proxy"

Answer (score 1):

Squid has a lot of features, and IMO is quite bloated for such a simple use-case; I'd suggest something more lightweight, like [tinyproxy](https://tinyproxy.github.io/) (docker image [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/vimagick/tinyproxy)). So what you can do is create a `Deployment` using that image, pin it to a specific node (the one with the IP that the 3rd party API allows) using [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector), create a `Service` pointing to it, and use that as a proxy in your requests. There's one drawback to this approach, though - you just added a(nother) single point of failure to your infrastructure.